# How to switch to another component onclick in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 components SignUp and Welcome in seperate files.
In SignUp component , I am checking if password and re-type passwords are same. If they are same..I have to switch to Welcome Component.

Can someone help me with this, as I'm new to "REACT" I'm having some trouble.
I've tried something like this, but ain't working :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import Welcome from './welcome'
class SignUp extends Component {
    state = {
        pwd : "",
        confirm_pwd : "",
    }
    handlepwd = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            pwd : event.target.value 
        });
    }
    handlecpwd = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            confirm_pwd : event.target.value 
        });
    }
    checkPassword = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(this.state.pwd == this.state.confirm_pwd) {
            return <Welcome/>
        }
        else {
            alert("Wrong Password!!! Check Again");
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="bg">
                <h1 className="heading">WELCOME TO STUDENTS LEARNING BYTE</h1>
                <div className="login_container">
                    <form>
                        <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label><br></br>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required/><br></br>
                        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label><br></br>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" value={this.state.pwd} onChange={this.handlepwd} required/><br></br>
                        <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label><br></br>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" value={this.state.confirm_pwd} onChange={this.handlecpwd} required/><br></br>
                        <label for="collegeName"><b>College Name</b></label><br></br>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your College Name" name="collegeName" required/><br></br>
                        <label for="branch"><b>Branch</b></label>
                        <select name="branch" id="branch">
                            <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
                            <option value="ECE">ECE</option>
                            <option value="IT">IT</option>
                            <option value="EEE">EEE</option>
                            <option value="CME">CME</option>
                            <option value="MECH">MECH</option>
                        </select><br></br><br></br>
                        <label for="semester"><b>Semester</b></label><br></br>
                        <input type="text" name="semester" placeholder="Enter your current semester" required/><br></br>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" /> Remember me
                        </label><br></br>
                        <div>
                            <span>
                                <button onClick={this.checkPassword}>SignUp</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

export default SignUp;
By clicking Signup button it calls the checkpassword function.

Comment: please share complete `SignUp` component code showing what is rendered.

Comment: @HemantMalik Yup changed!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use state to switch to welcome component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import Welcome from './welcome'
class SignUp extends Component {
state = {
    pwd : "",
    confirm_pwd : "",
    showWelcome:false, //add this
}
handlepwd = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        pwd : event.target.value 
    });
}
handlecpwd = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        confirm_pwd : event.target.value 
    });
}
checkPassword = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(this.state.pwd == this.state.confirm_pwd) {
       this.setState({showWelcome:true}) //set showWelcome as true
    }
    else {
        alert("Wrong Password!!! Check Again");
    }
}
render() {
if(this.state.showWelcome)
return <Welcome/>
else
    return (
        <div className="bg">
            <h1 className="heading">WELCOME TO STUDENTS LEARNING BYTE</h1>
            <div className="login_container">
                <form>
                    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label><br></br>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required/><br></br>
                    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label><br></br>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" value={this.state.pwd} onChange={this.handlepwd} required/><br></br>
                    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label><br></br>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" value={this.state.confirm_pwd} onChange={this.handlecpwd} required/><br></br>
                    <label for="collegeName"><b>College Name</b></label><br></br>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your College Name" name="collegeName" required/><br></br>
                    <label for="branch"><b>Branch</b></label>
                    <select name="branch" id="branch">
                        <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
                        <option value="ECE">ECE</option>
                        <option value="IT">IT</option>
                        <option value="EEE">EEE</option>
                        <option value="CME">CME</option>
                        <option value="MECH">MECH</option>
                    </select><br></br><br></br>
                    <label for="semester"><b>Semester</b></label><br></br>
                    <input type="text" name="semester" placeholder="Enter your current semester" required/><br></br>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" /> Remember me
                    </label><br></br>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            <button onClick={this.checkPassword}>SignUp</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
import React ,{ Component } from "react";
import Welcome from './Welcome;
```

```
class Test extends Component {
    state = { 
        pwd : "",
        confirm_pwd : "",
        isLoggedIn: false
     }

     checkPassword = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      if(this.state.pwd == this.state.confirm_pwd) {
          this.setState({isLoggedIn : true})
      }
      else {
          alert("Wrong Password!!! Check Again");
      }
   }

    render() { 
        return ( 
         <div>
           {isLoggedIn? <Welcome/> : <></>}
           
           /// login form

         </div>
        )
           
    }
}
 
export default Test;
```

### But the better way is:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-login-authentication-to-react-applications